# Nested Has Many Through Plugin and Named Scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database, has-many-through

I have a User Model(:name, :password, :email), and Event model(:name, :etc) and Interest model (:name) [>all singular<]

Then I created two join tables -> UsersInterests and EventsInterests; each not containing a primary key and only comprised of the user_id/interest_id and event_id/interest_id respectively. [>plural<]

My Models Use the   [Nested Has Many Through Plugin](http://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through)

```
user.rb => has_many :users_interests
 has_many :interests, :through => :users_interests
 has_many :events_interests, :through => :interests
 has_many :events, :through => :events_interests

event.rb => has_many :events_interests
  has_many :interests, :through => :events_interests
     has_many :users_interests, :through => :interests
  has_many :users, :through => :users_interests

interest.rb => has_and_belongs_to_many :users
               has_and_belongs_to_many :events

events_interests.rb => belongs_to :interests
                    belongs_to :events
users_interests.rb => belongs_to :users
                   belongs_to :interests
```

Whew..ok So I wanted to created a named_scope of that find all the events that share interest with a particular user. Here is some code someone helped me with.

```
named_scope :shares_interest_with_users, lambda {|user|
{ :joins => :users_interests,
  :conditions => {:users_interests => {:user_id => user}}
   }}
```

When i run from the controller =>

```
@user = User.find(1) 
@events = Event.shares_interest_with_user(@user)
```

I get the error :

```
uninitialized constant Event::EventsInterest
```

Can anyone see what i messed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have named something wrong along the way. At a glance I'd say you have a file or class named incorrectly. Remember model names **MUST** always be singular, both in file and class names or else Rails won't make the connection. Another source of your problem is that arguments to belongs_to must also be singular. Even if you had got things right, the HABTM relationship in interests with users would have thrown an error when you ran the named scope.

I was able to solve your error with the following models.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :users_interests
  has_many :interests, :through => :users_interests
  has_many :events_interests, :through => :interests
  has_many :events, :through => :events_interests
end
```

**users_interest.rb**

```
class UsersInterest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :interest
end
```

**interest.rb**

```
class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :users,:through => :users_interests
  has_many :users_interests
  has_many :events_interests
  has_many :events, :through => :events_interests
end
```

**events_interest.rb

```
class EventsInterest <ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :interest
  belongs_to :event
end
```

**event.rb**

```
class Event <ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :events_interests
  has_many :interests, :through => :events_interests
  has_many :users_interests, :through => :interests
  has_many :users, :through => :users_interests


  named_scope :shares_interest_with_users, lambda {|user|
    { :joins => :users_interests,
      :conditions => {:users_interests => {:user_id => user}}
    }
  }

end
```